# Как убрать из URL имя категории

Tags: joomla, php

Подскажите каким макаром можно убрать в Joomla 2.5 отображение имени категории в ссылке(URL).

Что бы было не так: http://domain.com/category/material

а так: http://domain.com/material

Слышал в каком то файле можно строку изменить, что бы не отображалось имя категории. Или может с помощью самой Joomla это можно как то исправить ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте в файле .htaccess написать

`#Удаляем category из URL
RewriteRule ^category/(.+)$ http://www.site.com/$1 [R=301,L]`

Не забудьте изменить [www.site.com](http://www.site.com) на ваше доменное имя

Comment: @Berserker Я обновил ответ. Прошу прощения, мой косяк

Comment: А покажите полный адрес, который по Вашему мнению должен подпадать под ваше правило

Comment: `mod_rewrite` включен вообще?
По правилам писать так:
<ifmodule mod_rewrite.c="">
Rewriturfeed eEngine on
RewriteRule ^materialy/(.+)$ http://sled3d.com.ua/$1 [R=302,NC,L]
</ifmodule>

Comment: mod_rewrite у меня включен. Выше изложенный материал вообще выдает 500 error. в .htaccess имеется функционал

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+) index.php?page=$1

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^sled3d.com.ua$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sled3d.com.ua/$1 [L,R=301]